# Lookup for a Range of Rows into another Range of Columns

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Please suggest modifications in my code to solve the following problem :
I want to look for a range of numbers (B5:C5) into another range of columns (T6:U32) and if its subset of (T6:U32). I want to copy the next column value. 
for example :  if (B5:C5) is subset of (T25:U25) then copy the cell value of "V25" to "I5". 
my code looks like this

```
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range,
Dim r As Range

Set range2 = Range("T6:U32")
Set range1 = Range("D5:E5")

For Each r In range2
    If Intersect(r, range1) Is Nothing Then 'do nothing
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next r
'copy next column cell value to "I5"
```

SNAPSHOT : 
[image]

Comment: Looks like you can just use SUMIFS.

Comment: @BigBen Yup, It's solved by using  "lookup" function. thanks for your suggestion